# Can this loop code be simplified somehow?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a problem... it's basically that my code is ugly and I don't like it. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify it (I use java 8)

I have these "code blocks" that follow this pattern, I have about **5 or 6 of them** within a method so this method looks very repetitive and ugly.

The loops are all the same, just the code varies inside.

Is there any way to simplify this?

#### CODE BLOCK EXAMPLE

```
            String id = null;
            for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS; i++) {

                // BEGIN VARIABLE CODE
                id = getPrice();
                if (id != null) break;
                // END VARIABLE CODE 

                // sleep between checks
                if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            }
```

#### EXAMPLE

```
            String id = null;
            for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS; i++) {

                // BEGIN VARIABLE CODE
                id = getPrice();
                if (id != null) break;
                // END VARIABLE CODE 

                // sleep between checks
                if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            }
            
            for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS; i++) {

                // BEGIN VARIABLE CODE
                x=x*2;
                if (x>25) break;
                // END VARIABLE CODE 

                // sleep between checks
                if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } etc... a couple more blocks
```

Comment: What is the rest of the code? I don't think it is possible to make major changes with such less of code

Comment: I can't see how you can simplify this code further... Only that you can just type String id; it's redundant to assign it's value to null since it is null by default also if you don't want the id variable to be used outside of this loop then you can go use yassin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about coding an *abstraction* to contain all the boilerplate?

```
class MyLoop
{
    private int numChecks;

    private int delay;

    public MyLoop(int numChecks, int delay) {...}

    public void loopAndSleep(MyTask task)
    throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Update: It is important to set properly the order of the looping conditions, 
        // to stop invoking hasEnded() as soon as i<numChecks==false (Thaks to Simon Eismann).
        for (int i=0; i<numChecks && !task.hasEnded(); i++)
        {
            if (i < numChecks -1)
            {
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            }
        }
    }
}

interface MyTask
{
    public boolean hasEnded();
}
```

So, you can replace each one of your 5-6 places in your program by:

```
new MyLoop(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY).loopAndSleep(new MyTask(){...});
```

By properly extending `MyTask` you can give them specific status variables.

Comment: Can you help me understand your solution? When is the exection of MyTask triggered? does the hasEnded() funktion have to contain the code we want to exectue aswell?

Comment: @Simon Eismann: Of corse. Look: My solution is the same as yours, but taking the loop method (which you have named `loopWithDelay`) to a new abstraction, to make it more reusable. Then you have declared a specific piece of code through a simple `Runnable`, and I have done it through a more specific `MyTask`, for the need that the method executed in every iteration must return a boolean to confirm if the loop must end or keep going on. And yes: The `hasEnded` function must contain the action code and the decission code.

Comment: kinda irrelevant case, but if numChecks is 0 you actually execute the action once and don't sleep, right? Thanks for your explanations btw :-)

Comment: @Simon Eismann Hum... Yes, you are right. But it would be enough to invert the order of conditions of the loop. I'll update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to try some operation until the return value is available, you may do the following (Java-8 way):

```
public static <T> Optional<T> retryWithDelay(int numberOfChecks, int delay, 
                               Supplier<Optional<T>> supplier) throws InterruptedException { 
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfChecks; i++) {
        if(i > 0)
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        Optional<T> result = supplier.get();
        if(result.isPresent()) return result;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
String id = retryWithDelay(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY, () -> Optional.ofNullable(getPrice()))
                   .orElse(null);
```

Or if you don't like optionals for some reason, you can stick with `null`:

```
public static <T> T retryWithDelay(int numberOfChecks, int delay,
        Supplier<T> supplier) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChecks; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        T result = supplier.get();
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
String id = retryWithDelay(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY, () -> getPrice());
```

Or using method reference:

```
String id = retryWithDelay(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY, this::getPrice);
```

Note that the second example with `x = 2*x` is more difficult as it has some mutable state. It can be solved in dirty way like this:

```
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(1);
Integer result = retryWithDelay(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY, () -> {
    int val = x.get()*2;
    x.set(val);
    return val > 25 ? val : null;
});
```

However I hope this version was just for illustration, not the real code.

---

There's also somewhat more sophisticated approach which probably abuses the API, but allows more flexibility. You can create an `IntStream` of increasing numbers, but they are available with given delay:

```
public static IntStream delayedStream(int numberOfChecks, int delay) {
    return IntStream.range(0, numberOfChecks)
                    .peek(x -> {
                        if(x > 0) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(delay);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // ignore
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

So the first problem can be solved now as:

```
String id = delayedStream(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY)
                  .mapToObj(x -> getPrice())
                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                  .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

And the second can be solved like this (assuming initial `x` value is 1):

```
int x = delayedStream(NUM_CHECKS, DELAY)
             .map(idx -> 1 << (idx+1))
             .filter(val -> val > 25)
             .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: yes the stuff in the variable code section was just for illustration that the code in that area is different in each block, most of the code I guess is more similar to the getPrice().. it makes REST requests and does something with the results, updating some variables that exist outside the loop. Thanks for this, I will spend time digesting it and see how to work it into my code. Although there are only about 5 or 6 code blocks in this method, I still need to implement a couple more methods that also make similar style requests.

Answer (score 1):

The structure you provide is called a "polling loop" and you are correct, it is poor programming style, as are all the replies that contain the same polling loop.

It would be far better to use events.

Look in the "getPrice()" function, get to wherever that return value is being changed, and create an event when the change happens. Then in your code write a handler and in the handler do all the stuff that currently happens after your polling loop succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to make to loop reusable, but this would only make sense if you use the loop a lot.

```
public void loopWithDelay(int numberOfChecks, int delay, Runnable r) { 
   if (numberOfChecks != 0) {
      r.run();
      loopWithDelay(numberOfChecks - 1, delay, r);
      Thread.sleep(DELAY);
   }
}
```

The actual call would look something like this:

```
loopWithDelay(5, 1000, new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                     //Variable code goes here
                  }
             });
```

On a general note, are you sure you want to wait DELAY seconds after an action or have the action occur every DELAY seconds?

EDIT:
I am dumb, no need for recursion, this works aswell:

```
public void loopWithDelay(int numberOfChecks, int delay, Runnable r) { 
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChecks; i++) {
      r.run();
      if (i != numberOfChecks -1)
         Thread.sleep(DELAY);
   }
}
```

Comment: pause after action. I want to not spam the servers with requests.

Comment: @Simon Eismann: You are right: No need for recursion, but your last approach is sitll recursive.

Comment: I should get some sleep, removed the leftover line :-)

Comment: Your solution lacks the ability of premature exit as required by op.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: His Variable Code contains breaks, which handle the premature exits. These should still work in my solution, right?

Comment: @SimonEismann, how would you break from inside of Runnable to quit the outer loop?

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: Crap you are right :-) I'd need to use a Runnable<Boolean> and then break if it returns for example true. But at that point it's pretty much exaclty the soltion propsed by Little Santi, so no point in editing my reply further i guess